# Magento 2 passing parameter from observer to itself

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I made an observer for the `catalog_product_save_after` event.

I need to do some changes to the "brother" products.

To do this, I get the parent product id and then all his childens.

For each children (except the product where the event was triggered) I do my mods and then I call the `save()` method of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory`.

When the `save()` method is called, another event `catalog_product_save_after` is triggered, so I'm in a loop.

I want to observe the event when the form is submitted from the admin panel only, and not when I save the product programmatically.

What i thought i would do is to pass a parameter when I call the `save()` method, so next time the event is triggered, if my parameter exists I quit my observer.

I tried setting a session parameter like:

```
$this->_session->start();

if( $this->_session->getMyParam() !== null ){
    return false;
}

$this->_session->setMyParam('true');

...

$this->_session->unsMyParam();
```

but doesn't work. It seems the MyParam is always set, so my function return false every time.

Please any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "normal" php Session.

// SET PARAMETER VALUE

```
$_SESSION['PARAMETER_NAME'] = SOME OBJECT
```

// GET PARAMETER VALUE

```
 $value = isset($_SESSION['PARAMETER_NAME']) ? $_SESSION['PARAMETER_NAME'] : null;
```

I use this cache prices from an external webservices and it works perfectly.